# Managing the stores of Redux and Apollo

Tags: redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to integrate an Apollo client (graphql) to my application that is already developed with reactjs and redux.

With the information I've got the Apollo client have a store as the redux have one too.

Is it good to work with 2 stores in the application ? is it possible to have only one store ?

Answer (score 1):

The Apollo Store will communicate directly with the GraphQL server and store data that comes back from it. The Apollo Store is the client side repository of all the data that is coming from the GraphQL server.

I do believe it is possible to only work with one, I also believe you should only work with one Store and that Store should be the Apollo Store since it is what is communicating with GraphQL and pulling in data to your React application.

So if in your `index.js` file you currently have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './components/App';

const store = createStore(() => [], {}, applyMiddleware());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

I imagine you would have to refactor it to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

import App from './components/App';

const client = new ApolloClient({});

ReactDOM.render(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
      </ApolloProvider>,
      document.querySelector('#root')
    );
```